# Why aren't my values transferring over

Tags: java

After I enter a value into my program, why aren't my values passing over? I know I'm missing something simple but I can't put my finger on it.

Any help would be appreciated.

The part I'm having issues with is in the "actionPerformed" method.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class PayBillGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

double totalDue = 0.0;
double taxRate = 0.0;
double tipRate = 0.0;
double totalOwed = 0.0;


private JButton calcBtn;
private JButton exitBtn;
private JLabel totalLbl;
private JTextField totalTxt;
private JLabel taxLbl;
private JTextField taxTxt;
private JLabel tipLbl;
private JTextField tipTxt;
private JLabel owedLbl;
private JLabel numOweLbl;

private  Container container;


public PayBillGUI(String title)
{
    super(title);
    setSize(225, 200);
    initializeUserInterface();
}

public void initializeUserInterface() 
{

    container = this.getContentPane();
    container.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,2));


    calcBtn = new JButton("Calculate");
    exitBtn = new JButton("Exit");
    totalLbl = new JLabel("Total Due: ");
    totalTxt = new JTextField(5);
    taxLbl = new JLabel("Tax Rate: ");
    taxTxt = new JTextField(5);
    tipLbl = new JLabel("Tip Rate: ");
    tipTxt = new JTextField(5);
    owedLbl = new JLabel("Total owed:");
    numOweLbl = new JLabel("$" + totalOwed);


    container.add(totalLbl);
    container.add(totalTxt);

    container.add(taxLbl);
    container.add(taxTxt);

    container.add(tipLbl);
    container.add(tipTxt);

    container.add(owedLbl);
    container.add(numOweLbl);

    container.add(calcBtn);
    container.add(exitBtn);

    calcBtn.addActionListener(this);
    exitBtn.addActionListener(this);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

    String buttonText = calcBtn.getText();
    if (event.getActionCommand().equals(buttonText))
    {
        container.remove(numOweLbl);

        totalDue = Double.parseDouble(totalTxt.getText());
        taxRate = (Double.parseDouble(taxTxt.getText()) / 100) * totalDue;
        tipRate = (Double.parseDouble(tipTxt.getText()) / 100) * totalDue;

        totalOwed = totalDue + taxRate + tipRate;
        container.add(numOweLbl);
        validate();

    }
    else
    {
        System.exit(0);
        validate();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: `"...why aren't my values passing over?"` -- What do you mean "passing over"?  Which values?  Where in your code is your problem?  What data do you expect do see?  What data do you actually see?

Comment: what is `validate()`? Also, this program will exit whenever any button other than the calcuate button is pressed. `System.exit()` should be removed from `actionPerformed()` method.

Comment: Might be something to do with exiting the program before calling `validate()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your else block in `actionPerformed` you exit before reaching `validate()`.

The problem is probably the following:

You are adding the `numOweLbl` to your UI, but you never set the text of it to `totalOwed`.

Before you do `container.add(numOweLbl)` you need to set its text.

```
numOweLbl.setText(totalOwed)
```